# When using temp.mkdir in node.js, the output file made by an exe that was called cannot be found in the temporary directory

Tags: node.js, temp

I've tried running the EXE without using temp.mkdir and it works fine with the input and output files appear in the main directory. However, I want to be able to use a temporary directory since I want node to create the input file, run the program with the created input file, and read the output file, and then delete the temporary directory to prevent the input and output files being saved every time the program is ran.

```
app.post('/Test', (req, res) => {
    const exec = require('child_process').exec;
    const execFile = require('child_process').execFile;
    const program = ".\\cpp\\a.exe";
    const input = req.body.input;

    temp.mkdir('test', (err, dirPath) => {
        const inputPath = path.join(dirPath, 'input.txt');
        const outputPath = path.join(dirPath, 'output.txt');
        fs.writeFile(inputPath, input, (err) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            const child = execFile(program, (error) => {
                if (error) throw error;
                fs.readFile(outputPath, function(err, data) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    const output = data;
                    res.render("test", {
                        progOut: output
                    });
                    exec('del -r ' + dirPath, (error) => {
                        if (error) throw error;
                        console.log("Removed " + dirPath);
                    })
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Code is probably very rudimentary, and inefficient but that's just me trying to debug certain parts.

Comment: The program you're running with `execFile()` doesn't seem to know anything about the temp directory you created as you aren't passing it to it as an argument and aren't changing the current directory to it.  How would it even know about it?  Or why would you think the program would use it?

Comment: FYI, you will notice that a [coding example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/temp#temporary-directories) in the `temp.mkdir()` documentation, passes the new temporary directory to the child process it is executing as a command line argument so that that program can then use that directory in its processing.  It seems that you need to do the same.

Comment: I thought since it was within temp.mkdir it would create the output file in the temp directory that was created. In the example, they use chdir to change it to the temporary directory, for me, my program path apparently doesn't exist. Also, I'm kind of confused about: `exec("texexec '" + inputPath + "'", function(err) {`. They concatenate the temporary directory in the middle of the program path but for me, I'd just want to call the a.exe. I'm sorry if I'm not understanding something right away.

Comment: Their `exec()` example is constructing a command line where the program is first, then followed by a space, then followed by the first command line argument just like you would type on a command line if you were passing command line arguments to a program you were running from your favorite shell.  You aren't even making your program ware of the temp directory you created so it just goes about its business like it always did and doesn't even know there's a particular directory you want it to use.